# Python - find number of passed arguments inside a function

Tags: python

Imagine I want to define a function with all arguments having default values:

```
def fun(a=2, b=1):
    ...
```

The logic inside the function is that: if nothing is passed, use the default value; if only a is passed, then b is always equal to a/2; if both a and b are passed, then use the passed values.

The problem in completing this function is that it seems difficult to tell the difference between (for example) **fun(4)** and **fun(4,1)** since I don't know whether the **b=1** is provided outside or is just the default value.

One obvious way to get around is to use *args, however, in my case I want to keep the default values and names. Therefore it seems the only way out is to know inside **fun()** how many arguments are passed when it's called. I guess there might be some system function to use, but I didn't succeed in finding them. Any idea how could this work would be very helpful.

Thanks! :)

Comment: So don't have the default argument `b=1`. Have (for instance) `b=None` and then work out inside your function what value `b` should take based on the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have (for instance) the default value of `b` be `None`, and then work out inside your function what value `b` should take.

```
def fun(a=2, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = a/2
    ...
```

This will give you:

```
f()    : a=2, b=1
f(4)   : a=4, b=2
f(4,1) : a=4, b=1
```

Comment: Thanks @khelwood ! That's a very clear and nice solution. Just out of curiosity, do you think it is possible in Python to know the number of arguments passed inside a function?

Comment: You could use some kind of decorator to trap the arguments before they go into the function, but I think it would still basically amount to an `*args, **kwargs` solution.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help!